# Delta in Grafana with MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, grafana

For my Bachelor's thesis I want to evaluate a photovoltaic system. I've got a MySQL-table, that is updated every minute. The inverters fill the values into a MySQL database, that I can look at with HeidiSQL.

To compare the different values, which are delivered in total Wh, I want to know the delta between the latest and the previous value.

I have a timestamp (dd.mm.yy , hh:ss), but no id.

Is there a way to get the delta and plot it in Grafana?

Comment: What part of the process are you having trouble with? Retrieving the right data, performing the difference calculation, or passing it to Grafana?

Comment: I have trouble with the calculation of the difference, because I don't know how I can access previous datapoints.

Comment: It might be useful to [edit] the question to include what fields are in the table. That way people can see if there is an id field, or a timestamp field and base an answer on that. If you include the table definition people would even be able to see which fields are indexed which could make for more efficient queries.

Answer (score 0):

i think this Bachelor's thesis is writen, but a possible solution may have been creating a view in mysql.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW vstatistic AS
SELECT s1.stampdate, (s1.value - s2.value) as deltaValue, (s1.value - s2.value) as deltaValue
FROM statistic as s1, statistic as s2
where s1.id = (s2.id +1); 
/* id is key autoincrement */
```

And now access this view as datasource in grafana.

If you have no autoincrement, and/or you do not want to rely on date functions or views, you may also solve this with a TRIGGER on INSERT writing in a new table, instead of using a view.

Comment: Joins are around for 30 years , don't you think you should start using them, also you can't expect that even auto_incremnt column are consecutive and as i read correctly he has no auto_increment in the first place

Comment: you are right, added another possibility.